# ion-searchbar IonClear não funciona

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Preciso criar um evento ao clicar no 'X' da barra de pesquisa.
Porém ao clicar no 'x' nada acontece, criei o evento (ionClear) porém não está entrando no método do componente.

HTML:

```
<ion-searchbar class="searchbar" inputmode="search" placeholder="{{ 'dash_incidents.tickets_view.filter' | translate }}"
                        [(ngModel)]="ticketSearchText" ngDefaultControl (ionChange)="searchTicket()" showClearButton="never"
                        (ionClear)="onClear($event)"
                        (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)">
        </ion-searchbar>
```

TS:

```
 onClear(event) {
      console.log('entrou no clear');
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Me chamou a atencao o seu showClearButton="never", tente tirar o mesmo... acabei de fazer o codigo abaixo e o mesmo esta funcional

```html
<ion-searchbar showCancelButton="true" cancelButtonText="cancel" debounce=250 placeholder="Search " (ionClear)="clear($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

```ts
clear(event)
  {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

funcionando!